# Speed of light estimate from Io's eclipses by Ole Rømer

Tags: speed-of-light, astronomy, measurements, eclipse, jupiter

It can be found elsewhere that Ole Rømer estimated the speed of light (in terms of UA/h, probably) by accounting cumulative delay in Io's eclipses.

**My question here is: how did he measure time with necessary precision? I mean: what was precisely his method and what time measurement instrument did he use?**

To make my question clear, cumulative observation of Io's eclipse is made for at least 90 consecutive days, from about Jupiter's opposition up to after its quadrature. Ole Rømer found a delay of about 25 min. Therefore, the precision in the measurement of Io's eclipse period must be way less than 25 parts in 90.

Comment: More on [Rømer's measurement](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%5Bspeed-of-light%5D+jupiter)

Comment: In the wikipedia article about [Rømer's determination of the speed of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B8mer%27s_determination_of_the_speed_of_light) it is mentioned: "Most of Rømer's papers were destroyed in the Copenhagen Fire of 1728". To my understanding: it is unknown how much information was in manuscripts that have perished. Whatever the case, very little information has survived. By necessity: the descriptions of Rømer's methods are reconstructions, educated guesses. I expect that all information that is available is (already) in the wikipedia article.